# Error while pushing elements to a vector inside a lambda function

Tags: c++11, lambda

Below lines of code give error:

```
std::vector<std::string> strVect;
auto pushToVector = [strVect] () {
    strVect.push_back(std::string("Hi"));
};
pushToVector ();
```

> error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

But when I pass `strVect` by reference in lambda there is no error.

```
std::vector<std::string> strVect;
auto pushToVector = [&strVect] () {
    strVect.push_back(std::string("Hi"));
};
pushToVector ();
```

NO ERROR

Please let me know why do we get error in fist scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables visible to lambda using `[variable]` syntax are copied. Also lambda's `operator()` is `const`, unless `mutable` is specified.

```
std::vector<std::string> strVect;
auto pushToVector = [strVect] () mutable {
    strVect.push_back(std::string("Hi"));
};
pushToVector ();
```

However, it does not do anything usefull, because it copies `strVect`, `push_back` element to it, and after return from the lambda, the copy is gone.

Comment: The variables aren't `const`, the function call operator is.